# IE8 'Invalid argument' in small jQuery animate snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've got a list where every time an item is added, the last item should be removed. I've got it working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but IE refuses.

Not sure why, but IE8 throws an Invalid argument error at some point. I believe I have tracked it down to this portion, but I don't know where or why. Just in case the error is actually outside this portion, you can see a more complete, working (or not working in IE8) [version here](http://jsbin.com/ufiray/).

```
first.animate({top:0}, 250, function() {
    first.animate({marginTop: oldMarginTop}, 500, function() {
        last.animate({top: olPaddingBottom}, 125, function() {
            //Remove the old element
            last.remove();
            //Reset the CSS we changed
            stream.css({
                height: 'auto',
                overflowY: 'visible'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

first and last are selected nodes from the list. First is the newly created list item, and last is the one we will be removing.

Comment: I always find it helpful to develop my code using the non-minified version of any scripts (like jQuery), that way the errors that occur in crappy browsers can still be traced to specific code without looking for column 20,125 in the minified code.

Comment: Have you checked the console in firefox or chrome? I have issues with IE that are not existent in chrome, but chrome still throws and error normally more accurate than IE.

Comment: @Jasper I agree, but Chrome has an awesome 'pretty print' function that makes minified code slightly easier to read.

Comment: MS has a great debugger that is free withing Web Developer Express. It is great for stepping through JavaScript code to pinpoint problems. It also has an useful editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use instead of oldMarginTop....

```
parseInt(0+oldMarginTop,10)
```

for me  IE returns "auto" for `oldMarginTop` , this value cannot be animated, you need a numeric value( the suggestion  will set the value to 0 when it is not a numeric value)

http://jsbin.com/uvepit/

Comment: Brilliant! This answer got me on the right track - I was trying to animate `marginTop:''` - seemed to work fine in Webkit/Gecko/IE9, but died in IE<=8.

Comment: It can be a number, a string with a number then `px`, or a string with a number then `%`. Note that IE8 can handle decimals, **unless the number is less than 1** (I had a problem where real browsers handled an animation from `0.xxxx%` fine, but IE8 would fall over unless it was rounded up to `1%`, even though it could manage `1.xxxxx%` fine).